# Manage Acknowledge with Mutiny when transforming Message to Multi<Message>

Tags: quarkus, mutiny

I am trying to transform a single input message into multiple messages. I've got a method with the following signature:

```java
@Incoming("CH_IN")
@Outgoing("CH_OUT")
Multi<Message<B>> process(Message<A> in) {

}
```

The Class `A` is like:

```java
class A {
    private List<String> ids

    // getters and setters
}
```

For each `id` in `A` I would like to create an instance of `B`. **How could I do this and deal with acknowledge of `in` message?**

This is a simplification of what I have, but I am not sure if this is the right way of doing it:

```java
@Incoming("CH_IN")
@Outgoing("CH_OUT")
Multi<Message<B>> process(Message<A> in) {
    List<Message<B>> out = new ArrayList<>();

    // Code to iterate ids and create instances of Message<B>
    // In certain cases the out list will be empty

    return Multi.createFrom().iterable(out).on().completion(in::ack);
}
```

**Is it the right way of acknowledging the in message?**

Answer (score 0):

> This is a simplification of what I have, but I am not sure if this is the right way of doing it

It'll work so long as you don't need any blocking calls in your commented processing section, but it's not ideal IMHO:

- Stylistically, mixing imperative & reactive code in the same method isn't very neat
- Functionally, this approach won't allow you to call any blocking code in your processing if you need to (now or in the future.)

Instead, I'd advocate something like:

```
return Multi.createFrom().item(in)
        .flatMap(m -> Uni.createFrom().item(m).repeat().atMost(5)) //Replace with your actual processing
        .on().completion(in::ack);
```

...which keeps the entire method as one reactive chain, and gives you the ability to `flatMap()` to other publishers if you need to (if your processing requires a web call, database call or some other blocking IO for instance.)

> Is it the right way of acknowledging the in message?

So long as you only want the ack to happen on completion of processing, yes.

The only downside is that, if a catastrophic failure occurred half way through processing, conceivably some could be processed before `in` was acknowledged. The only other sensible behaviour would be to use `on().subscribed()` instead, which just creates the opposite problem (`in` will be acknowledged but some or all messages may not be posted to your outgoing channel.) Which one is preferable depends on your use-case.